# MS Access SQL Query with grouping across rows and columns

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a table in MS Access with following layout. I am using MS Access 2019

```
Category1  Qty1   Category2 Qyt2
================================
A           10       B       2
B           3        C       4
A           2        A       4
C           3        B       3
```

I want the output as

```
Category     Qty
================
A             16
B              8
C              7
```

Please suggest how to achieve this using query in MS Access.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNIONALL` and `GROUP BY` in inner sub query

HERE CHECK [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/698f7/17)

```
  SELECT Category, SUM(Qty) as Qty FROM (
        SELECT Category1 AS Category, Qty1 AS Qty FROM TAB1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Category2 as Category, Qty2 AS Qty FROM TAB2
    ) as TAB
    GROUP BY TAB.Category
```

Answer (score 1):

Rearrange data with UNION query into normalized structure should be in first place.

```
SELECT Category1 AS Cat, Qty1 AS Qty, 1 AS Src FROM tablename
UNION SELECT Category2, Qty2, 2 FROM tablename;
```

Use that query as source for an aggregate query.